# Unable to find my saved usernames and passwords

Tags: python, csv

I am creating a user login system in which you can create and save your own logon, however when I try to get python to check if the username entered is a saved logon, it always returns a negative result, even when the username is in the file.

I've tried changing file types and rearranging code, but nothing seems to work. Is this just me being stupid?

```
import csv

inputUser=input("Enter your username")
with open('Usernames.csv', 'r+') as savedUsers:
    if inputUser in savedUsers:
        with open('Passwords.csv', 'r+') as savedPass:
            inputPass=input("Enter your password")
            if inputPass in savedPass:
                print("Welcome back,", inputUser)
            else:
                print("Incorrect Password")
                raise SystemExit()
```

I expect that when I enter a username saved in the `Usernames.csv` file it will move on to "Enter you password" but in fact it always moves on to do you want to create a logon, the output for if your username is not found.

Comment: `savedUsers` here is a *file object", not the text content of the file. Do some research about the basics of file handling in Python and come back if you are still having problems.

Comment: Why are you importing `csv` and then never using it?

Comment: Would you really want to authentication someone just for giving any known username and any used password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: You've opened the file but not the text contents as Robin suggested. Try looking at savedPass.read() or savedPass.readlines() to assist.

Good practices:
You should use getpass so the password isn't listed in the console.

Additionally, try checking out libraries like [bcrypt](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/) for handling hashing passwords (a very good thing to do!)